# Too many queries for each user to assets table in joomla

Tags: joomla, query-optimization

My site generate a lot of queries to database, for each user generates 6 queries. I tried to fine the source of that but my knowlegde was not enough to find. If anyone could help me how to fine the source of that queries?

I used:

- Joomla 2.5.8
- Main Components: CB, Kunena, SH404SEF, K2, Komento, UddeIM PMS
- Main Modules: Gavick News PRO4
- Block spam IP
- Block bots

The queries which are generate for each user:

```
SELECT *
FROM `_users`
WHERE `id` = 15

SELECT `g`.`id`,`g`.`title`
FROM `_usergroups` AS g
INNER JOIN `_user_usergroup_map` AS m ON m.group_id = g.id
WHERE `m`.`user_id` = 15

SELECT b.id
FROM _user_usergroup_map AS map
LEFT JOIN _usergroups AS a ON a.id = map.group_id
LEFT JOIN _usergroups AS b ON b.lft <= a.lft
                           AND b.rgt >= a.rgt
WHERE map.user_id = 15

SELECT a.rules
FROM _assets AS a
WHERE (a.id = 1)
GROUP BY a.id, a.rules, a.lft

SELECT id
FROM _assets
WHERE parent_id = 0

SELECT b.rules
FROM _assets AS a
LEFT JOIN _assets AS b ON b.lft <= a.lft
                       AND b.rgt >= a.rgt
WHERE (a.id = 1 OR a.parent_id = 0)
GROUP BY b.id, b.rules, b.lft
ORDER BY b.lft
```

Answer (score 0):

well of course there are going to be a fair amount of queries per use, as you are using extensions such as CB and Kunena, that include queries for each user. Unless you get a message from your host saying too much memory is being used or there is too much traffic, you should be fine.

Joomla is a CMS and therefore these sort of things need to be expected when there are a fair amount of users.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I never find information that these components generate a lot of queries. At the kunena forum I got answer that kunena can't be source of these queries. Did you met with similar problem on the other websites? I didn't get information from my host abaout using too much memory but 1700 queries is little disturbing.

Comment: @user2000424 - If you to to the Joomla backend, then go to **Global Configuration**, then **System**, then turn on **Debug System**. Refresh the frontend of your site and it will show you the database queries and which extensions they are coming from

Answer (score 0):

Actually we just fixed a bug in the rules field that was generating an excessive number of queries.  It will be fixed in 3.0.4 which is due out next week and whenever another 2.5 release comes out. In the meantime you can fix it yourself.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/pull/1792

But that's not what you are asking about. The number of queries isn't really the issue (it's totally reasonable) the question is how fast are they.